# Mongod DB update array element order with condition

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to sort Mongodb array elements with condition

suppose my array is like

```
{
   "id":1,
   "array":[
        {
           "id" : "150",
           "place" : "US"  
        },
        {
           "id" : "1250",
           "place" : "UK"  
        },
        {
           "id" : "1350",
           "place" : "AUS"  
        }
   ]    
}
```

Then I want to sort and update "array" 
Eg : I want to arrange array element value "id" in order 1250 , 1350 , 150

My updated document will look like

```
{
   "id":1,
   "array":[
       {
           "id" : "1250",
           "place" : "UK"  
        },
        {
           "id" : "1350",
           "place" : "AUS"  
        },
        {
           "id" : "150",
           "place" : "US"  
        },
   ]    
}
```

Comment: do you want to push the first element of the array to the last right? rotate by one?

Comment: Not rotate, i want to arrange order according to given order of value of id

Answer (score 2):

Use the [**$push**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#push-modifiers) operator with the [**$each**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) and [**$sort**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort) modifiers.

```
db.collection.update({"id":1},
                     {$push:{"array":{$each:[],$sort:{"id":1}}}})
```

Passing an **empty** array to the `$each` modifier, ensures that no additional elements are added and only the existing elements are sorted based on the `id` field in ascending lexical order(since `id` is of string type).

> To use the `$sort` modifier, it must appear with the `$each` modifier. You
>   can pass an empty `array []` to the `$each` modifier such that only the
>   `$sort` modifier has an effect.

If you would want to sort it based on some priority on the id field then you could do it in you application code as below:

```
// define an array of elements with decreasing priority
var sortOrder = ["1250","1350","150"];

// find and update all the documents
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    var arr = doc.array.sort(function(a,b){
        return (sortOrder.indexOf(a.id) - sortOrder.indexOf(b.id));
    })
    db.collection.update({"_id":doc._id},{$set:{"array":arr}});
})
```

But the best way I would suggest is to maintain the order when you insert the document or update the `array` field.

Have a mapping for the `id` field to determine the order in which the elements need to be sorted in the array field.

```
var sortOrder = ["1350","1250","150"];
```

Whenever you want to `insert/update`, perform an [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update) operation using the [**$position**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) operator, which `inserts/updates` the array field with the new element in the appropriate position based on the `sortOrder` array.

```
var elementToInsert = {"id":"1350","place":"UK"};
db.collection.update({"id":1},
            {$push:{"array":{$each:
                        [elementToInsert],
                      $position:sortOrder.indexOf(elementToInsert.id)}}},
            {"upsert":true})
```

Comment: I got this , but i want to arrange it with given order of ids like if i want to keep element with id value 1250 at first position, element with id value 1350 at second position and 150 at third position, so how should i do that

Comment: If you can't specify the order you want with an argument to `$sort` in the above solution, you need to retrieve the document, modify the array client side to be in the appropriate order, then update the document in the database with the new, resorted array field.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.find().sort( { id: 1 } ).pretty();
```